# Python download file in link

Tags: python, python-requests, python-webbrowser

I want to open a link using python on  same tab. I use web browser module but all open in default browser ,but I want to open in same browser and same current tab.

```
webbrowser.open(URL)
webbrowser.open_new_tab(URL)
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample of your code so we can see exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Once you open webPage you have no controll over the page. As webbrowser open command will retrun True or False depending on either webpage successfully open or not.